# In IIS7, how can I require Authentication on specific directories?

Tags: authentication, iis-7

I have a website on Win 2008 and IIS7. Some directories have admin specific pages and I don't want regular site users to be able to access them.

What I would like is, if the user tries to load a page from a specific directory, for the site to popup a windows authentication window if the user has not not already authenticated.

Can this be done? Preferably just by setting web.config keys?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `<location></location>` tags to override the current IIS settings at that level and set new ones.

Reference: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: That MSDN link is broken.

Comment: Good catch, they updated with IIS push in Windows 8.1.  Updated.